# Python Matrix multiplication using for loop

Tags: python, loops, matrix, integer

```
from numpy import linalg
from numpy import matmul



M = [[2,1],[1,3]]
b = [[3],[-1]
Mb = [] 

nrows = 2
ncols = 2
for i in range(0,nrows):
    sum = 0
    for j in range(0,ncols):
        sum = sum + M[i,j] * b[j]
     Mb[?] = ?   

print(Mb)
```

#the goal of this was to multiply matrices using a loop. I keep getting the error (python list indices must be integers not tuple) when trying to run this. I'm not sure what I need to put in place of the question marks inserted.

Comment: Why do you need a for-loop if you're using the numpy library? `b` doesn't look like a valid list.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in this array indexing: `M[i,j]`. Built-in nested (not truly multi-dimensional) python arrays cannot be accessed in this way, you must index the dimensions one at a time: `M[i][j]`.

You may see python code that does use this indexing, but that is with 3rd party libraries such as `numpy`.

Comment: the inner array syntax issue is solved but I am seeing the error "list assignment index out of range" when running with Mb[I] = sum on the second to last line

Comment: As your code is currently written, `Mb` is empty so you cannot assign a value to any elements. One solution is to instead use `Mb.append(summation)` - where I've replaced your `sum` with `summation` just as the comment from @catasaurus says because `sum` is a builtin name.

Answer (score 0):

To access an inner array, you use this syntax:

```
sum = sum + M[i][j] * b[j]
```

Comment: you shouldn't name any variables `sum`, it is a built in function so it is a bad practice to do so.