# Python Matrix Multiplication integers using for loops

Tags: python, matrix, multiplication

```
from numpy import linalg
from numpy import matmul



A = [[1,2],[2,3]]
b = [[5],[2]
Ab = [] 

nrows = 2
ncols = 2
for i in range(0,nrows):
    sum = 0
    for j in range(0,ncols):
        sum = sum + A[i][j] * b[j][0]
    Ab[?] = ?  

print(Ab)

exit()
```

I am not sure what to put in place of the questions marks " Ab[?] = ?" I tried "Ab[i] = sum" but that does not seem to be working. I need this code to print the results of the multiplied matrices listed in A and b.
Is the line "sum = sum + A[i][j] * b[j][0]" right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Matrix multiplication using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71700881/python-matrix-multiplication-using-for-loop)

Comment: also, same typo missing a closing `]` in b when copying the question.

Comment: that was an error from copying and pasting

Comment: so why do you post the question again if you have answers in the other question?

Comment: Its not that question does not give the proper answer in the output

Comment: From the linked question: "As your code is currently written, Mb is empty so you cannot assign a value to any elements. One solution is to instead use Mb.append(summation)"

Comment: i tried that and it does not give the out I am looking for